# Typescript - making property as public in destructuring constructors

Tags: javascript, typescript, destructuring

Is there a way to make property as public in Destructuring for constructors?

Supposed to be there are many properties in Person Class.

Instead of

```
// to create a Person. new Person('')
class Person {
    constructor(public name: string) {

    }
}
```

I want to use destructuring to pass object as constructor parameter and make properties as public.

```
//new Person({name: ''})
class Person {
    constructor({
        public name: string //Is there a workaround here?
    }) {

    }
}
```

Is there a workaround here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No currently that is not possible but there is an active discussion around this on this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5326)

Comment: I will mark it as a correct answer until there's an implemented version for this. Thanks.